# Emacs, how to work remotely using ssh?

Tags: ssh, emacs

I would like to edit remote files with Emacs using an ssh connection. Is it possible with the default packages of Emacs 23.2 ?

If it is possible, what's the best way to do it ? Is it possible to benefit from the Speedbar ? Or even to compile remotely (C++ environment) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`TRAMP`](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/TrampMode) package.

```
TrampMode is a part of Emacs starting with version 22.1.
```

Comment: Thanks. And about the speed bar ? Is it possible ?

Comment: I made a quick test and yes, it seems possible. Since `TRAMP` stands for `Transparent Remote Access, Multiple Protocols` I'm expecting that most of the common functionalities work *transparently*.

Comment: this thing just hang for me, is there any other choice